# I would like to the simulation to switch on and off gradually

Tags: animation, fluid-simulation

I am creating an animation of a hard block that is softened by being pushed from above, and then crushed by further pushing.

Hard blocks are expressed by turning off the simulation.
For soft blocks, the simulation is turned on.

However, with the above method, the animation switches in one frame.
Is there any way to make it so that it gradually becomes softer?

[image][image][image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are several possibilities:

- You could bevel the hard block before (so it is rounded).
- Or increase the resolution of your domain (which will cost a lot of baking time).

Comment: Thank you for reply!

I'm sorry, I didn't write it right.
1. hard block (I want to show that the block is hard at first, so I would not like to bevel)
2. hard block is pressed
3. block becomes soft
4. further pushed and crushed
I would like to make this 1-2 process smooth and gradual.

If I increase the resolution of Domain, will the process of 1-2 change smoothly and gradually? (I have increased the resolution from 32 to 128 and am baking)

Comment: Yes it will. But you might have to increase it even more to get your result. Maybe first try with a very small domain just to check how it looks and fits your needs.

Comment: Really! Thank you for polite! I will try it !